# If $V$ is right-orthogonal, does it hold $\langle AV,BV\rangle_F=\langle A,B\rangle_F$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A,B\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. It's easy to see that for the Frobenius inner product it holds $$\langle A,B\rangle_F=\operatorname{tr}B^\ast A=\operatorname{tr}A^\ast B.\tag1$$ So, if $U\in\mathbb R^{k\times m}$ is left-orthogonal (i.e. $U^TU=I_m$), then $$\langle UA,UB\rangle_F=\operatorname{tr}B^TU^TUA=\langle A,B\rangle_F\tag2.$$ Can we show an equivalent result for right-orthogonal (i.e. $VV^T=I_n$) $V\in\mathbb R^{n\times k}$ and $\langle AV,BV\rangle_F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the cyclic property of the trace (see [Is trace invariant under cyclic permutation with rectangular matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252272/is-trace-invariant-under-cyclic-permutation-with-rectangular-matrices) )
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle AV, BV \rangle_F &= \mathrm{tr} V^T B^T A V \\
&= \mathrm{tr} B^T A V V^T \\
&= \langle A, B \rangle_F
\end{aligned}
$$