# Prove that if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, then $\text{trace}(AB) = \text{trace}(BA)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Not sure how to start this proof, it's for linear algebra.

Prove that if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, then $\text{trace}(AB) = \text{trace}(BA)$.

Comment: What work do you have so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is trace invariant under cyclic permutation with rectangular matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252272/is-trace-invariant-under-cyclic-permutation-with-rectangular-matrices) (As well as several questions linked from that one.)

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot, thank you.